# TrueCrypt - ran "decrypt" by accident on wrong disk which was not encrypted - how to "encrypt" it back?

Tags: security, encryption, truecrypt, disk-encryption, decryption

basically I had normal, not encrypted disk, which I thought is my truecrypt drive. I booted from `TrueCrypt Rescue Disk.iso` and selected "Permanent Decrypt my data". It complained about key data being overriden - fine, i restored it from that same CD, and then ran `decrypt`.

Of course that made my data go away. However, AES is the symmetric algorithm, and, I'm thinking, if I run `encrypt` command over previously "decrypted" data (with the same master key/headers), I should get my data back. Am I correct? Any clue how can I do this?

Comment: anything wrong with my question to downvote it? please explain - i'm more than happy to improve..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

looks like i'm not the only one. Somebody already created a tool for that: 
https://cryptoservices.github.io/truecrypt/2015/04/21/truecrypt-back-to-front.html - the story, and the tool: https://github.com/nccgroup/Untrue